# Github Mac Permission Issue

Tags: macos, git, github, ssh

I'm using the latest Github for Mac as a new Git user. When I try to sync a repo (that I first cloned, then created a new branch, commited changes, and then merged with master), I got the error:

```
Authentication Failed.

You may not have permission to access repo111. Check Preferences to make sure you’re still logged in.
```

I searched for similar questions, but the answer seemed to be add SSH keys to github, so I followed: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys.

When I do `ssh -T git@github.com`, I get:

```
Hi User111! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

I'm logged in as the correct user, and have rights to the repo, so I'm not sure why I'm not authenticated?

Comment: Can you show the different commands or URLs you use to communicate with GitHub ?

Answer (score 26):

It could be that you entered a password incorrectly and it's stored in your keychain.

For my situation, I was using GitHub for Mac to work with a BitBucket repository. Long story short, I mistyped my BitBucket password and GitHub for Mac could not authenticate (because the password stored in my keychain was wrong).

Thanks to the [helpful folks at GitHub](https://github.com/contact), they quickly responded when I asked for help:

> Open `Keychain Access.app` (in `/Applications/Utilities`) and search for "GitHub for Mac." There should be an entry like "GitHub for Mac — bitbucket.com". Delete that entry

---

## Steps to fix if using GitHub for Mac to manage a BitBucket repo

If you see this:

[image]

… then you might have a **BitBucket** keychain/password problem.

Open `Keychain Access.app` (in `/Applications/Utilities`) and search for `bitbucket`:

[image]

Right-click on the entry and get info:

[image]

Click on "Access Control" to confirm that it's truly the GitHub for Mac BitBucket password/login keychain item:

[image]

Rather than deleting the keychain entry/item, I just edited my password:

[image]

You should now be able to use GitHub for Mac without authentication failures. :)

Comment: Omg. Wow. Such a tiny edit, but very hidden. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 18):

Had the same problem, but it was not a password problem, since other repositories worked just fine.

Finally compared `.git/config` with a working repository and found this:

This failed:

```
[remote "origin"]
  url = github@github.com/path/to/repository
```

This worked:

```
[remote "origin"]
  url = https://github.com/path/to/repository
```

Still have no idea how or why this changed.

Comment: This happened seemingly randomly on like a third of my repositories. I have no idea why, is very weird. Thanks for the fix!

Comment: Only thing that worked for me; thanks! Mine was a tad different, the original path looked more like this: `git@github.com:path/to/repository` so I had to change that colon to a forward slash to match your second path.

Comment: If you are on OSX and your repo is on github this is the best answer, thanks @Nik. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: @msmfsd - nope, not a clue. It hasn't happened to me since though.

Comment: Got the same problem with Fork for Mac, and this worked ! Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I had to try some other stuff after the solutions above didn't work out for me.

Dont know why I got this issue, or why was fixed after:

1. deleting the existing keys:

`.ssh/github-rsa`
`.ssh/github-rsa.pub`

2. restarting GitHub Desktop, which automatically regens the keys
3. add new keys to repo host (bitbucket etc)

Comment: This worked for me, but I also had to delete all the existing SSH keys in my GitHub account that had been generated over time. Somehow GitHub Desktop was choking on multiple keys for the same computer.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, then I followed this steps:

1. Login to BitBucket and go to the repository you want to use
   Click the “Clone” button, and change the drop down option to HTTPS.
2. Copy the command that appears (something like: git clone https://username@bitbucket.org/team-name/repository-name.git)
   Open terminal in your mac and navigate to wherever you want the theme files to be stored.
3. Paste the clone command in the terminal, press enter and then enter your password when requested.
4. In Github for Mac go to the repositories screen and click the + sign in the status bar.
5. Select Add Local Repository – and then select the repository of the folder you want to add.
6. Done

Comment: That did it for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If your password is correct and you still see have this problem, chances are your .git/config file has some miss configuration.

In my case, it had a pushurl value under [remote "origin"] which was not needed (I was working on a cloned project).

Comment that line by adding a # before it and you are good to go :)

Also, if you get an error saying:

> This repository is configured for Git LFS but 'git-lfs' was not found on your path. If you no longer wish to use Git LFS, remove this hook by deleting .git/hooks/pre-push

just delete that by doing

> rm .git/hooks/pre-push

now you are all set. This happened to me also using github desktop app for mac, with a remote bitbucket repo.

hint: if you commit changes and refresh bitbucket to see the changes, those might not show, but navigate to the root of the project and then back to the file and you'll see the changes. Probably some cache issue but it can drive you mad if you don't know this hint.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created remote repository on GitHub and merged with local repository or project .
you can add that local repository to GitHub desktop app 
than go to  Repository > repository settings > Remote >

under remote You'll find primary remote repository (origin)
there's a ssh remote url delete that And

1. Go to your GitHub account.
2. Open Your Remote repository
3. click on Clone or Download
4. Copy the https URL
5. paste that in the GitHub desktop app
6. click on fetch in the Desktop GitHub App
7. It'll work Great :)