# Github Permission Error

Tags: github-for-mac

I created a new branch from master just testing it and pushed "publish", but it says this:

Authentication Failed
You may not have permission to access c. Check Preferences to make sure you’re still logged in.

But when I got to preferences, I am logged in.

"c" is the name of the folder.

Comment: Possibly related (if using GitHub for Mac): http://stackoverflow.com/q/25047468/922323

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I had cloned someone else's repository and it was trying to publish to their repository rather than my own.

Comment: You need to fork it, push and pull on own repository and If you feel like to contribute, create a pull request and then send them back.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after cloning someone else's repo and the advice to fork it resolved the issue.